# Searching in multiple tags is treated as an OR when used in combination with user:xxx

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search

My intent was to find this question [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-re-write-those-class-defined-in-primefaces-css) to see if it's useful enough to vote as a duplicate or to include as a "see also" link in a new answer.

So I searched using the keyword [user:me [primefaces][css]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:157882%20%5Bprimefaces%5D%5Bcss%5D). However, it unexpectedly returned 775 results. It seems that the tags are not searched using the AND condition. Without the "user:me" as in [[primefaces][css]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primefaces+css) it returns 67 results. I tried to fix the search query to be [user:me +[primefaces] +[css]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:157882%20%2b%5Bprimefaces%5D%20%2b%5Bcss%5D&submit=search), but no cigar. It still shows all the 775 results.

Replacing "user:me" with "inheritance" as in [inheritance [primefaces][css]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inheritance%20%5Bprimefaces%5D%5Bcss%5D&submit=search) yielded exactly 1 result, exactly the answer I was looking for (currently, it's 2 results ;) ).

So it seems that the tags are incorrectly treated as an OR condition when used in combination with "user:me". This seems a nasty bug to me. Can we please fix it?

Comment: Nice to see you're using the same searches I use, whenever I need a JSF answer. Well, actually I use Google as that allows for typing BalusC rather than some user id ;-)

Comment: + 1 to yourself + @Arjen : I agree with Arjan here. I also use Google for searching my post in SO. So in your case try this `stackoverflow BalusC primefaces.css` in Google

Comment: Well, @Siddharth, I was not trying to say I am using Google to search *my own posts* :-) And, Stack Overflow is [not the only nice resource](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/) one gets when searching for BalusC, so I don't even limit to stackoverflow.com in my Google searches!

Comment: @SiddharthRout why not a search like `BalusC primefaces.css site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: Yup :) you can do that as well. Google in that matter is very flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These go through the same code path now, so the effect is no longer and `OR` but an `AND`, consistent with other searching.  An `OR` search ability is coming, I just need a few hours to get it done.

Comment: Well done, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this search query:

[user:157882 [primefaces] + [css]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A157882+%5Bprimefaces%5D+%2B+%5Bcss%5D&submit=search)

Notice the use of `plus` indicating `AND` not `OR`.

It gives me 20 results, which are all tagged how you wanted.

Comment: Wow. It's the space which solved it. If you remove the spaces around the `+`, it fails again. Is this in turn a bug or "by design"?

Comment: @Chichiray no clue. Good luck to you, though!